# Strange output of sprintf, Whats causing it?

Tags: c, printf

I'm trying to use sprintf this way:

```
        DebugLogMsg10 (DebugStruct, sizeThreadID, "szLoginHeadString before:\r\n%s",szLoginHeadString );

        sprintf (szLoginHeadString, "<br/>%s", szLoginHeadString);

        DebugLogMsg10 (DebugStruct, sizeThreadID, "szLoginHeadString after:\r\n%s",szLoginHeadString );
```

I don't understand the resulting strings.

[Thu Feb 20 14:49:01 2014][Thread:0]    szLoginHeadString before:

```
<form name="login_from" action="http://PLACEHOLDER.com" method="post" accept-charset="ISO-8859-15">
```

[Thu Feb 20 14:49:01 2014][Thread:0]    szLoginHeadString after:

```
<br/><br/> name="login_from" action="http://http://PLACEHOLDER.com" method="post" accept-charset="ISO-8859-15">
```

I would be expecting something like

```
<br/><form name="login_from".....
```

What am I not thinking about?

Comment: `sprintf` is terribly unsafe. Prefer `snprintf`.

Comment: debuglogmessage is used alread for like a half year and never amde trouble (also is jsut printing stuff to file). And szLoginHeadString is in the current test mode `char szLoginHeadString[4096]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code invokes undefined behavior. The `sprintf` family functions cannot be given arguments that overlap in memory, as described in the manpages:

*C99 and POSIX.1-2001 specify that the results are undefined if a call to sprintf(), snprintf(), vsprintf(), or vsnprintf() would cause copying to take place between objects that overlap (e.g., if the target string array and one of the supplied input arguments refer to the same buffer).*

Comment: This answer would stand on its own a bit better if you quoted the manpage.

Comment: Which manpages? I thought already something like this but couldn't find in ISO IEC 9899 or the freeBSD project man page fprintf family.

Comment: @Filipe Gonçalves just mistipped. http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sprintf&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD+4.7-RELEASE&format=html   can't find it in here.

Comment: @Zaibis I would say that manpage is incomplete. See POSIX documentation for `sprintf`: http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sprintf.html

Comment: Well to know. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It might be relative to your C library, but in common sprintf is operating with your memory, not copying string before edit, so at begin it overwrites beginning of your string woth "
" and then adds your string (already overwrited) to itself. So you have two 
`s and no .

**Do not use one string as source and as output in the same time.**